# How to check string contain in NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my application I have One MutableArray comes like this,

```
Idlist:(
1,
2,
3
)
```

I have one string IdData. in IdData value is 2.

Now i want to check Itemid contain in my MutableArray.

I have tried with this,

```
 if ([Idlist containsObject:IdData])
 {
   NSLog(@"Item is in List"); 
 }
 else
 {
   NSLog(@"Item is not in List"); 
 }
```

But every time I going to else loop.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure the items in your array are strings?

Comment: What do you mean by idData value is 2? idData = @"2" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code like this to identify NSString in your array:

```
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arr addObject:@"Best"];
    [arr addObject:@"Good"];
    [arr addObject:[NSNumber  numberWithInt:3]];

    for(NSString *str in arr)
    {
        if(str && [str isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
            NSLog(@"String: %@\n",str);    
        }
    }
```

Comment: That loop would be better written `for( id obj in arr ){ if( [obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] )` You don't have to check that it's non-nil -- you'd never get into the loop if it wasn't, and putting objects into the wrong pointer type is bad style.

Comment: @Josh Caswell, Yes, we can also use id instead of NSString, thanks a lot.